# Flutter : No valid Android SDK platforms found in /usr/lib/android-sdk/platforms. Directory was empty

Tags: android, dart, sdk, flutter

I have already installed the latest Android Studio and Android SDK on my computer. But I still have this trouble, anyone can help me to fix this? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Did you check what the directory contains?

Comment: Yes, i did. The directory empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio go to menu > Tools > SDK Manager
and ensure you have at least one platform selected, like `Android 9.0 (Pie)`

[image]

Click "OK" to start installation.
You can open SDK manager again and check it shows "Installed" on the right.

When it is done, check `flutter doctor -v` again.

Comment: It was already installed on my Android Studio and still like that

Comment: How about if it installed on linux vps with no gui ?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provide a command to update the SDK path.

```
flutter config --android-sdk <SDK folder>
```

For example, if the sdk installation is /opt/android/sdk, the command is:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /opt/android/sdk
```